# AngularJS - Unit testing service with value dependency injection

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am currently experimenting with AngularJS. I have created a simple service, which is initialized from some distant data. The url is passed as an application value.

```
//App declaration
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.services']).value('someUrl', 'http://www.example.com');

//Service declaration
angular.module('myApp.services', ['someUrl']).factory('MyService', function(someUrl) {
    var data;
    "Do stuff"  
    return data;
});
```

Now, I am trying to unit test this, but I cannot manage to correctly set the "someUrl" parameter. I have tried things like this, without succes:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.services']).value('someUrl', 'test/test.json');

describe('Services', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myApp.services'));

    describe('MyService', function() {
        it('should return {success: true}', inject(function() {
            expect(data).toEqual({success: true});
        }));
    });
});
```

However, I always receive a "No module: someUrl" error. What is the correct syntax to initialize an app value during a unit test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You setted value to "myApp" module and is testing "myApp.services" module. You should change `module('myApp.services')` to `module('myApp')`.

Anyway, there is a better way to do so. You can use mock `module` to inject `$provide` so you can override any dependency.

This is how your spec would look like:

```js
describe('Services', function() {
  // here we load the module myApp and load an additional one that
  // allows you to override your dependency
  beforeEach(module('myApp', function($provide) {
    $provide.value('someUrl', 'test/test.json');
  }));

  describe('MyService', function() {
    it('should return {success: true}', inject(function() {
        expect(data).toEqual({success: true});
    }));
  });
});
```